Delete Survey Translation
I created a Survey and translated it. Now i want to remove a complete translation, because it is not necessary anymore. Is there a way to delete a survey translation?
This is how the UI looks when we add Survey Translations (taken from Salesforceben)


Ressources that i did not find useful but go into this direction:

API Delete Survey Translation
Salesforce Translation Workbench (thought this is only for administration and not to delete one particular survey translation from one particular survey)

